# Program is not quitting when choice 2 is entered instead it is asking to enter a positive number. What is the issue here?

Tags: java, loops, menu, exit

The program is not quitting when choice 2 is entered instead it's asking to enter a positive value. It should only ask that if the choice was 1 and then the number of rooms entered was less than one. It should immediately quit the program but it's not. What can I do to fix this? Is it because of braces missing or extra ones.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class Paint {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###0.00");
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         double numbGallons;
         double costPerGallon;
         double totalSquareFeet = 0;
         double numbHours;
         double costPerHour;
         double paintCost1;
         double squareFeet;
         int choice;
         int numRooms = 0;
         double laborCost1;
         double totalEstimate;

         do {
             displayMenu();

             choice = keyboard.nextInt();

             if (choice == 1) {
                 System.out.println("How many rooms do you want to paint?");
                 numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
             }

             while (numRooms < 1) {
                 System.out.println("Please enter a positive value");
                 numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
             }

             for (int counter = 1; counter <= numRooms; counter++) {
                 System.out.println("How many square feet of room " + counter +
                     " do you want to paint?");
                 squareFeet = keyboard.nextDouble();
                 totalSquareFeet = totalSquareFeet + squareFeet;
             }
             System.out.println("The total square feet is " + totalSquareFeet);

             numbGallons = numGallons(totalSquareFeet);

             numbHours = numHours(totalSquareFeet);

             System.out.println("How much is the price per hour?");
             costPerHour = keyboard.nextDouble();

             System.out.println("How much is the price per gallon?");
             costPerGallon = keyboard.nextDouble();

             laborCost1 = laborCost(costPerHour, numbHours);

             paintCost1 = paintCost(numbGallons, costPerGallon);

             System.out.println("The number of Gallons is " + numbGallons);
             System.out.println("The number of Hours is " + numbHours);
             System.out.println("The labor cost is " + laborCost1);
             System.out.println("The paint cost is " + paintCost1);

             totalEstimate = laborCost1 + paintCost1;
             System.out.println("The total estimate is " + totalEstimate);

         } while (choice != 2);


     }

     public static void displayMenu() {
         System.out.println("1)Calculate Estimate");
         System.out.println("2)Quit the program");
         System.out.println("Please make a selection");
     }

     public static double numGallons(double sqr) {
         return sqr / 115;
     }
     public static double numHours(double sqr) {
         return (sqr / 115) * 8;
     }

     public static double laborCost(double cph, double nh) {
         return cph * nh;
     }

     public static double paintCost(double ng, double cpg) {
         return ng * cpg;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Consider posting a [mre] properly indented. You're more likely to get help if you make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You should show the menu and get the choice before entering the loop, and at the end of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###0.00");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double numbGallons;
    double costPerGallon;
    double totalSquareFeet = 0;
    double numbHours;
    double costPerHour;
    double paintCost1;
    double squareFeet;
    int choice;
    int numRooms = 0;
    double laborCost1;
    double totalEstimate;

    displayMenu();
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (choice != 2) {

        //if (choice ==1)
        //{     
        System.out.println("How many rooms do you want to paint?");
        numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
        //} 

        while (numRooms < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive value");
            numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= numRooms; counter++) {
            System.out.println("How many square feet of room " + counter +
                " do you want to paint?");
            squareFeet = keyboard.nextDouble();
            totalSquareFeet = totalSquareFeet + squareFeet;
        }
        System.out.println("The total square feet is " + totalSquareFeet);

        numbGallons = numGallons(totalSquareFeet);

        numbHours = numHours(totalSquareFeet);

        System.out.println("How much is the price per hour?");
        costPerHour = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How much is the price per gallon?");
        costPerGallon = keyboard.nextDouble();

        laborCost1 = laborCost(costPerHour, numbHours);

        paintCost1 = paintCost(numbGallons, costPerGallon);

        System.out.println("The number of Gallons is " + numbGallons);
        System.out.println("The number of Hours is " + numbHours);
        System.out.println("The labor cost is " + laborCost1);
        System.out.println("The paint cost is " + paintCost1);

        totalEstimate = laborCost1 + paintCost1;
        System.out.println("The total estimate is " + totalEstimate);

        displayMenu();
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();

    }
}
```